# Yii2. Как добавить правило в urlManager

Tags: yii2, rules, url-manager

Подскажите пожалуйста правило urlManager для адреса вида

site.name/controller/action/id1/id2/.../idN/var1

Количество id в строке может быть разным.
Спасибо

Comment: А зачем такое нужно? Что-то страшное) категория-подкатегория-подкатегория-подкатегория-подкатегория?))

Comment: Такая реализация уже используется. Нужно переписать на Yii2. Это не категория-подкатегория-... это товар/товар/товар...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 'pattern' => '<controller>/<action>/<ids:.+>/<var1>',
'route' => '<controller>/<action>',
'params' => [
    'ids' => '<ids>',
    'var1' => '<var1>'
]
```

и екшн будет таким

```
    public function actionMethod($ids, $var1) {
   // code
}
```

Правило будет совпадать линками:

```
    site.name/controller/action/id1/id2/.../idN/var1
site.name/controller/action/id1/id2/var1
site.name/controller/action/id1/var1
```